# Set the value of a different field when a field value changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm using Angular Schema Form and I want to set a model property to null when a field value changes. I've tried using `onChange` in the form definition like so

```
{
  key: '7_11',
  type: 'radios',
  titleMap: [{value: 'no', name: 'No'}, {value: 'yes', name: 'Yes'}],

  onChange: function(modelValue,form) {
    if (!modelValue) {
      // model['8_1'] = null
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the model property I'm trying to set is bound to a different field than the field that has changed

I can't do it in the manner indicated by the comment, because `model` is not in scope in the `onChange` listener.

### Update

A second example is [this Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CSd5tT?p=preview). Say we want to clear the 2 checkboxes (by removing the corresponding properties from the model) whenever some text is entered in the Name field, how could this be achieved?

I should also point out that for reasons I won't bore you with, I can't implement this using a conditional and `destroyStrategy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not uncommon (because it is kind of natural) to set the model and the form inside the scope of the same controller. 
If that is the case, you can set X by `$scope.model.X = modelValue`.

Or perhaps you are in a position where you can't reach the scope of the model, in that case it is more complicated. On the other hand I would recommend to do it all in the same place.

(Sometimes that is not possible. For example, I have dynamic forms and schemas in my application, however in those cases I use generalized functionality like the filter functionality in [ASFDS](https://github.com/OptimalBPM/angular-schema-form-dynamic-select#filters) or [ASF conditions](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#condition) and avoid hard-coding UI using onChange) .

For example, this would set foo2 if foo is changed in the plunkr:

```
onChange: function(modelValue,form) {
    if (modelValue) {
        $scope.model.foo2 = ["Yes"];
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you have time, could you take a look at the Plunker demo, and explain how the specific problem I mentioned in my update could be solved?

Comment: Ok, I see now, AFAIK, the onChange function is part of a field in the form, not in the schema property list.

Comment: You're right, I've moved it to the form, but I still don't see how I can set the value of field X from the `onChange` listener bound to field Y?